# Imagemagick convert -fill does not change edges from a particular palette area

Tags: php, ffmpeg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When I am trying to remove `Green (#09f80c)` color from this image using below command

```
magick convert images/img001.png - fill transparent -opaque #09f80c images/tp.png
```

I am getting below image:

[image: Input Image]

This image I get as an output for above command. This image still has some green dots at the edges. How to remove them completely?

[image: Output Image]

I want converted image not to have those extra pixels.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Imagemagick, you can use -fuzz as Andy suggested. But you can only increase the fuzz value so far before it starts changing other regions as well as the green.

Start by measuring the color as close as possible. I get #2FF81D

Here is about a large a fuzz value as possible for this image. But it still has some green on the outside. (Unix syntax)

```
convert green.jpg -fuzz 35% -transparent "#2FF81D" green_trans1.png
```

[image]

To further reduce the effect, you can antialias the border of the transparent area by blurring it a little and tapering (via -level).

```
convert green.jpg -fuzz 35% -transparent "#2FF81D" -channel a -blur 0x3 -level 50x100% +channel green_trans2.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `-fuzz` argument e.g `-fuzz 40%`.

I found this in the documentation here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please give me full command in case of my scenario. As I already tried with -fuzz but it gives me some other irrelevant result